# What happened to the CCLA?

Tags: correspondence-chess

I wonder what happened to the CCLA. Did the CCLA get folded into ICCF or USCF  or just go out of business?  Did it merge with yet some other chess group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They appear to still be active.

https://www.serverchess.com/